# I can't find my bitcoin address

Tags: electrum

i am using electrum. First, I had a bitcoin address and I used it once to receive BTCs and then it changed. but new address is invalid.
i tired so many times. i checked all the options. but it was not OK.
what shall i do?
thank you

Comment: Invalid according to who?

Comment: i checked according https://awebanalysis.com/en/bitcoin-address-validate/

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: select `Show Addresses` item from the `View` menu. Then click the `Addresses` tab.

---

> **First, I had a bitcoin address ...**

A [Hierarchical Deterministic (HD) wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet) has many addresses.

> **... and I used it once to receive BTCs and then it changed.**

That is normal, for privacy reasons, an HD wallet will generate a new receive address for each transaction in which you will receive BTCs.

> **I can't find my bitcoin address**

Look under the "Addresses" tab

[image: example]

*(from [a beginners guide](https://bitzuma.com/posts/a-beginners-guide-to-the-electrum-bitcoin-wallet/))*

> It will be hidden by default. To reveal it, select `Show Addresses` item from the `View` menu.

---

> **i checked according awebanalysis.com/en/bitcoin-address-validate**

I don't know that site but maybe you mis-typed an address or that site doesn't know about the [type of address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address) your wallet is using. Some online sites are not up-to-date with the latest Bitcoin features (e.g. Bech32 type addresses that start `bc1`...). Try another, for example http://lenschulwitz.com/base58