# Sent Bitcoin to my electrum wallet address without hitting request first now it says its confirmed and i have no money after requesting it

Tags: transactions, electrum

Sent Bitcoin to my electrum wallet address without hitting request first now it says its confirmed and i have no money after requesting it after Isent it. Can I still receive my coin

Answer (score 1):

> **Can I still receive my coin**

For privacy, many wallets use a new receiving address for each transaction but sending money to an old address should still work.

You can use one or more of the public [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer)s to find out the status of transactions involving the old address.

---

### Addresses

To view a full list of addresses known to your wallet see [I can't find my bitcoin address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/85977/13866)

If the address to which you sent the money is not on that list, it is possible you sent the money to someone else's address and have lost the money with no chance of recovery. If you have multiple wallets or deleted a wallet and reinstalled the same software or another, it is possible you sent the money to an address that no-one has control over (unless you were diligent in making and retaining backups of the wallet and records of the private-keys and/or recovery phrases)

If the address is on that list and shows a balance of zero, where blockchain explorers show a non-zero balance, it is likely there is a problem with synchronisation.

---

### Synchronisation

See [I didn't receive a Bitcoin Payment. What does it mean when the Client is synchronizing?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2124/i-didnt-receive-a-bitcoin-payment-what-does-it-mean-when-the-client-is-synchro)

If your wallet is having problems synchronising, you won't see your money until it succeeds

An unofficial [Electrum Beginner's Guide](https://bitzuma.com/posts/a-beginners-guide-to-the-electrum-bitcoin-wallet/) says:

> You can monitor progress from the Network window. Access it by clicking on the circle to the lower right of the main window. When the block count under “Blockchain” equals the height indicated for the servers you’re connecting to, Electrum will be fully synchronized and all confirmed transactions should be displayed properly under the History tab.

If the servers that Electrum connects to are themselves not synchronising, your wallet might not know that it is not  synchronised with the main body  of the bitcoin blockchain network. -- **check the blockchain height in your wallet in the network tab** (`blockchain: nnnnn blocks`) - make sure it agrees with blockchain explorers --

---

### Checking "balance" using another wallet

Download and install a new wallet (e.g. on another computer you own)

#### Watch-only

Import the *address* into the new wallet

Note that this doesn't mean the address is yours and gives you no ability to spend money at that address.

#### Full-Access

Export the Private key from Electrum

> Wallet > Private Keys > Export.

Import the *private key* into the new wallet

---

Footnote, probably unrelated:

### Electrum phishing & theft

According to https://electrum.org/#home currently

> Warning: Electrum versions older than 3.3.3 are vulnerable to a phishing attack. Do not download Electrum from any another source than electrum.org.

There are fake versions of Electrum which steal your money.

Comment: Blockchain says its complete and that it's at the the address but it doesnt show up in my wallet

Comment: See [I can't find my bitcoin address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/85977/13866) - is your address shown in the full list of addresses in Electrum?

Comment: Yes  it is shown on the list and the balance says zero,  but when I right click it and  click view on block explorer it says the address has the funds

Comment: My electrum wallet says it never received or started to receive anything but it says its complete on blockchain

Comment: Is there a way I can access an address from electrum wallet on blockchain

Comment: You can download & install a different wallet and either: import your [private keys](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key) from Electrum or use a [recovery/seed-phrase](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase) of a type that both wallets support. I think Electrum doesn't use the standard BIP39 seed-phrase system so choices may be few.

Comment: If you specify the address, people may be able to assist you to work out what is happening (or they may not be able to add much)

Comment: Ok I'm going to try that thank you for your help. It's very appreciated

Comment: See also blockchain height in revised answer. Don't forget to up-vote any answers you find helpful.